# Machine Learning, Imputing values that should be blank

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, data-imputation

Sometimes data sets contain variables that indicate the presence of an event and the value that represented the event.

As an example say a teacher wants to predict the grades of his students. Some of the students may have been in his class last year and he can use that grade as a variable. However maybe only 20% of the students were in his class so the rest of the 80% will have a Null value. Most ML algorithms cannot accept Null values so the variable would have to somehow be imputed.

I cannot think of an imputation method that would make sense here, the standard mean/mode would imply that all students were in the class and since the variable is pretty unbalance and 80% of the values would be imputed I don't imagine it would hold any valuable information.

Are there any methods to deal with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is usually latent information in the null/missing value which a tree model or deep network can signal out.

It gets a bit trickier in the peculiar case where 80% of the response is missing. It might be a good idea to wait for more data or try imputation with a probabilistic model (maybe a Bayesian model for imputation).

Anyhow, being able to classify the non-passing students is probably just as important though ;)

A boosted zero or one inflated beta regression might help you out here, as you could classify the non-passing students and run a beta regression over the grades at the same time. You would be sharing information in the gradient boosting as well.

I probably wouldn’t bother with deep learning here, unless you’ve got a substantial amount of data. LightGBM and Xgboost tends to work just as well if not better on structured 2d tensors.

Answer (score -2):

First, no algorithms can accept null as an input (as in, no value passed), but many can deal with the concept or representation of null in an appropriate way. If you are using a sophisticated learner such as a neural network or tree based method, then it will have no problem learning from values that represent null, so you could fill with 0 or anything that is outside of the range of grades. You could also potentially aid the learning algorithm by passing an additional parameter such as binary yes/no indicating if the student was in class last year. This is really only an issue if you are using something simple like OLS where the hypothesis space is limited to a linear combination of inputs.

Without knowing what algorithm you are working with I cannot provide a more specific answer, but I recommend reading about the hypothesis space of different ML algorithms.

[example showing LSTM can learn that a value means missing](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-timesteps-sequence-prediction-problems-python/)

Also I love the downvotes with no explanation, keep them coming!